# If question is closed already when I try to review Close Votes, error message is mismatched

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, error-message

Normally, if I'm too slow to contribute to closing a question in the CV queue, the error message is pretty reasonable: "This question is already closed. Please refresh the page." (Or words to that effect.)

Recently, though, at least on MSE, the error message in those cases is completely wrong. It tells me I can only open the close dialog every 3 seconds. While true, that's utterly irrelevant and entirely misleading.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: One of them is close votes in review; the other is answer flagging out of review. I don't think they're the same thing.

Comment: 99% sure it is the same root cause.